# Use variable in File.write

Tags: ruby, variables

I have been using the following to append something to a file.

```
File.write(file, 'something', mode: 'a')  # In case of plain text
File.write(file, myvar, mode: 'a')        # In case of variables
```

I have three requirements as below.

1. To use plain text and variables both

   ```
   File.write(file, mytext1=var1, mode: 'a')
   ```
2. To use combinations of plain text and variables

   ```
   File.write(file, mytext1=var1, mytext2=var2, mode: 'a')
   ```
3. To use multiple variables at the same time

   ```
   File.write(file, var1, var2, var3, mode: 'a')
   ```

These codes are not working.

In the above 3 points, mytext1 and mytext2 are plain text, could be anything say DNS1 and DNS2.
var1, var2 and var3 are variables, say 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11, and 192.168.1.12.

I can achieve this by deleting the line, adding a string, and replacing the string with `gsub` (in which variable works), but I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do it with `File.write`.

Comment: Your point 1 and 2 is confusing.. Can you make it clear ?

Comment: I have edited my question. mytext1/2 are just plain text (could be anything) and var1/2/3 are variables.

Comment: What are the two requirements? You have three bulleted points.

Comment: It is not clear what you need to delete, add, and replace.

Comment: @sawa I am just trying to use File.write with combination of variables and text, and more than one variable at once. I am not sure whether it is possible with File.write. I do not want to delete/replace anything just add another line which has variables and text as well. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Arup Rakshit, I found two easy solutions.

```
# using puts
File.open(file, 'a') do |j|
  j.puts "DNS1=\"#{ip}\""; 
end

# Using File.write
content = ("#{var1}\t#{var2}\t#{var3}\n")
File.write(file, content, mode: 'a')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`IO#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-i-puts) as

```
File.open(file_path, 'a') do |file|
  file.puts [var1, "your text", var2] # or puts var1, "your text", var2
end
```

The documentation of `#puts` is :

> Writes the given objects to ios as with `IO#prin`t. Writes a record separator (typically a *newline*) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. **If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.** If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

Or, you could probably do with [`File::write`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-write):

```
content = [var1, var2, var3].join("\n")
File.write(file, content, mode: 'a')
content = ["mytext1=#{var1}", "mytext2=#{var2}"].join("\n")
File.write(file, content, mode: 'a')
```

Comment: Thanks Arup, I think I need to use '()' brackets with puts. '[]' throw the below error `block in <main>': undefined method []' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Also, when using puts,values which are separated by ',' are printed in different lines.

Comment: @vikas027 There needs to be a space between `puts` & `[`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks, but still two lines get added to my file. I want the output in one line. For e.g. DNS1=192.168.1.27

Comment: @AndrewMarshall and @Arup. This works for me `File.open(file, 'a') do |file|;  file.puts "DNS1=#{ip}"; end`

Comment: @vikas027 Ok.. That's an interpolation you were missing.. :) If this answer helped, please accept to help the Community.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, that did helped me but I was looking a way out using File.write. The code just looks a but more cleaner using File.write IMHO. Thanks a ton for your time and efforts on this.

Comment: @vikas027 try it.. :)

Comment: Definitely, I will update this post if I come across a way with File.write. I am still driving on the learning curve for ruby, converting all my bash shell scripts into ruby. Hopefully, one day I will be efficient and competent in Ruby (as I am in shell scripting).

Comment: @vikas027 I gave the `File::write` version too.. :) Did you see?